# How to add a category in main menu in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, menu, topmenu

I am new in ***Magento 2***. Can anybody can tell me that how I add a category to the main menu. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Login to Admin:
Step 1) Click on Catalog >> Categories.
Step 2) Select Category you want to add in main menu. And select "Include in Menu" => Yes
Step 3) Run command php bin/magento cache:flush
Now check in frontend category show in main menu.
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a category from Admin.
Use following path.

> Magento Admin >> Products >> Categories

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add your category in `Admin->Catalog->Categories` be sure to have the `Include in Menu` set to yes also don't forget to clear cache if you have it all enabled

Answer (score 0):

To add categories to the main menu follow below steps.

1. From Magento, Admin Dashboard go to Catalog -> Categories
2. Select existing category or add a new category. Enable the option "Include in Menu" to "Yes".
3. Save category.
4. Clear cache if the cache is enabled.